# Randomly getting "The reply address does not match the reply addresses configured for the application..."

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

Randomly I am getting the  does not match the reply address configured for the application  after logging in through AD. If you go to the site URL again, it lets you in without this error. Sometimes it processes normally without the error. How do I prevent this from happening at all?

[image]

Comment: Don't add different domain URLs into the Reply URLs. Try to delete the second URL in the Reply URLs.  Azure does't allow this action. Refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add different domain URLs into the Reply URLs.

Try to delete the second URL `Https://localhost:44331/signin-oidc` in the Reply URLs.  There is a Limitation for the Reply URLs of Azure AD Application.

See more details about this restrication in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#limitations).

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: It helped, but it leaves a completely new configuration for a development machine. Localhost is what was being used for the dev box, but taking that out is now getting the same error in development (obv).  
  
Should there be separate app registrations for each environment?  
  
Seems counter productive when the AppID is used all over the place to call the graph and what not.

Comment: Yes, If you have to test both environment, you need to register different applications for test.